# I am publish(emiting) through redis on node from laravel but all the process works in queue i want to run simultaneously

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, redis

I am facing issue when i am emitting  from laravel through redis in node and all the process of the redis is in the queue and i want to work simultaneously

```
 $data['db_name']=$_GET['db_name'];
 $data['task_id']=$_GET['task_id'];



   $redis = new \Predis\Client('tcp://127.0.0.1:6379'."read_write_timeout=1");

  $redis->Publish('message',json_encode($data));
```

Here after sending or publishing it is waiting for the request to completed after that it will send request to the next queue i mean emit to it

Comment: Please provide some code and the error you are getting, otherwise we can't help that much

Comment: How many workers do you have?